# JavaFX layered layouts with shadows

Tags: java, javafx, ui-design

I am learning about JavaFX and I am trying to create an `AnchorPane` which includes in itself 3 more `AnchorPane`s. Currently, I have a problem where the shadow of the panel is hidden because of the panel next to it. So I need some suggestion on how to fix this issue.

I have tried to create a distance between them, but then I can see a white layer behind. I have tried to change z-order of the layer, doesn't seem to work, so now after 2 hours of not knowing what to do, I am asking here. maybe someone knows.

My code:

```
    DropShadow dropShadow2;
    AnchorPane iconPane, menuPane, viewPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        dropShadow2 = new DropShadow();
        dropShadow2.setOffsetX(6.0);
        dropShadow2.setOffsetY(4.0);

        //Main layout
        AnchorPane main_layout = new AnchorPane();

        //Icon layout (left)
        setUpIconLayout();

        //Menu layout (center)
        setUpMenuLayout();

        //View layout (right)
        setUpViewLayout();

        main_layout.getChildren().addAll(iconPane, menuPane, viewPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(main_layout, 1000, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Delivery System Database");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void setUpIconLayout() {

        iconPane = new AnchorPane();
        iconPane.setPrefSize(50,600);
        String hexColor_left = "D64550";
        iconPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + hexColor_left);
        iconPane.setEffect(dropShadow2);
    }

    private void setUpMenuLayout() {

        menuPane = new AnchorPane();
        menuPane.setPrefSize(200,600);
        String hexColor_mid = "EA9E8D";
        menuPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + hexColor_mid);
        menuPane.setEffect(dropShadow2);
        menuPane.setTranslateX(50);
    }

    private void setUpViewLayout() {
        viewPane = new AnchorPane();
        viewPane.setPrefSize(700,600);
        String hexColor_right = "DAEFB3";
        viewPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + hexColor_right);
        viewPane.setEffect(dropShadow2);
        viewPane.setTranslateX(250);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably won't help the main issue, but you might want to consider using an [`HBox`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) for the root rather than an `AnchorPane`. Also, adding the imports and class declaration to your example would make it complete (and thus easier to experiment with ourselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child nodes are rendered in the order they’re added, so it should be sufficient to add them in reverse order:

```
main_layout.getChildren().addAll(viewPane, menuPane, iconPane);
```

Answer (score 1):

As @VGR said, child nodes are rendered in the order they appear in the children `ObservableList`. This means children at a higher index will be rendered on top of children at a lower index. Because of this the shadows are being covered by the other nodes in your example. Since you're using `AnchorPane`, which uses absolute positions set by the developer, a simple fix is to reverse the order of the child list (as [shown by VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936532/6395627)).

That solution won't work well if you use a layout which also *positions* its children based on the order of the child list, such as `HBox`. You could work around this by setting the appropriate translate transformations but that's not recommended. Instead, you can set the [`viewOrder`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#viewOrderProperty) property—added in JavaFX 9—of the children. This property:

> Defines the rendering and picking order of this `Node` within its parent.
>
> This property is used to alter the rendering and picking order of a node within its parent without reordering the parent's children list. For example, this can be used as a more efficient way to implement transparency sorting. To do this, an application can assign the `viewOrder` value of each node to the computed distance between that node and the viewer.
>
> The parent will traverse its `children` in decreasing `viewOrder` order. This means that a child with a lower `viewOrder` will be in front of a child with a higher `viewOrder`. If two children have the same `viewOrder`, the parent will traverse them in the order they appear in the parent's `children` list.

Since you want previous children rendered above subsequent children you can simply set the `viewOrder` to their index in the `children` list. Here's an example:

```
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlurType;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox root = new HBox(createRegions(50.0, 200.0, 700.0));
        root.setPadding(new Insets(0.0, 75.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            root.getChildren().get(i).setViewOrder(i);
        }
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("ViewOrder Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Region[] createRegions(double... prefWidths) {
        return DoubleStream.of(prefWidths).mapToObj(prefWidth -> {
            Region region = new Region();
            region.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            region.setPrefSize(prefWidth, 600.0);
            region.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            region.setEffect(new DropShadow(BlurType.THREE_PASS_BOX, Color.BLACK, 10.0, 0.0, 6.0, 4.0));
            region.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, null, null)));
            return region;
        }).toArray(Region[]::new);
    }

}
```

---

You mention one of the solutions you tried was setting the Z-Order of the children but that it didn't work. In order for setting the `z` coordinate to work you must enable depth buffering when creating the `Scene`. You can test this by modifying the above example:

- Change `setViewOrder(i)` to `setTranslateZ(i)`.
- Change `new Scene(root)` to `new Scene(root, -1.0, -1.0, true)`

This has the benefit of working in JavaFX 8.